# module.exports not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js

I would like to export one function in node and call it in another file. Somehow it is always executing the whole code in the exporting module (not only the function exported).

```
//file:  test.js

module.exports = function () {
console.log("Hello");
}

console.log("Hello2");



//file: test2.js
var test = require("./test");
test();

// Desired Output: Hello
// My actual Output: Hello2 Hello
```

Can somebody please explain, why it is also running the second log (Hello2) although this log is not within the exported brackets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `require` a file, you import the entire file and it gets executed.  Since `console.log('Hello2');` isn't defined in a function, it gets executed when the file is required.

This is why you should see `Hello2` first.  And then you call the `test` function which executes and prints out `Hello`.

Your output should be:

```
Hello2 
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Vito, for the explanation. Is there a possibility to only call the function and not execute the whole other code?

Comment: Negative.  Why do you have the other code in there if you don't want it to execute?  And if this clarified things, could you tap that up arrow ;)

Comment: True. Thanks for the help, VTo!

Answer (score 0):

Try to do a named export,

**for example:**

```
module.exports = function first () {
  console.log("Hello");
}
```

**and in your test2.js:**

```
var test = require("./test");
test.first();
```

Comment: The name doesn't matter.  It's a matter of how `require` works and executes the entire file that you import.

Comment: Had to call the importName.functionName() to make it work, rather than importName()

Answer (score -1):

When you do `var test = require("./test");` you are requiring the *whole* file, rather than just the module you exported. In the file where you wish to use the function, you need to *import* the function from the other file.

Try doing this:

```
//file:  test.js

module.exports = function () {
console.log("Hello");
}

console.log("Hello2");



//file: test2.js
import { test } from './test'
test();
```

Comment: This will error, or test will be undefined, because you are trying to destructure a function.